# Duplicate question trees

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, duplicate-question

There's a [question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/25993/blur-a-transparent-image) that was closed as duplicate of a question that was closed as dup of another question.

I think this is counterintuitive.

It would be more consistent if the latest question was closed as dup of the earliest. So people don't have to click through a bunch of times to get an answer.

Comment: The question has been changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a good idea to keep this meta question open, you bring up a good point. Duplicate trees are indeed a pain and can be confusing. Ideally, all duplicates should point to a single question.

If you find another duplicate chain that you think needs sorting out, flag one of the posts for moderator attention and we can quickly resolve it.